# transfer data from database to another database android java

Tags: android, database, performance, sqlite, connection

I am trying to transfer data from a database A to another database B within the same application but query execution on the second database is extremely slow(15 secs or more)
so here is what I am doing.

1. connect to database A and start doing some processing....

   SQLiteDatabase databaseA = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(Constants.IMPORT_DATABASE_PATH,
              null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY | SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);

   //query some tables on database A and start doing some processing and connect to database
   B in the process
2. connect to database B and continue processing

   SQLiteDatabase databaseB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(Constants.DATABASE_PATH,
            null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE | SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);

//query execution with database B is extremely slow. very simple query like 'select colum1 from table1'

both databases are fairly small,300MB and 4MB

The queries within the databaseA execute very fast, normally. but the queries within databaseB execute extremely slow, like 14 sec or more.

Has anyone have this same issue before? is it possible to Concurrently connect to 2 different sqlite databases in android? what are the issues? how to solve them? obviously it's possible to connect but query execution in second database connection is very poor?

Thanks for replying or reading

Comment: I just attended a seminar for this exact question. Funniest thing is the first thing the guy said in the seminar was that Android was slow with db connections etc, and there was no real cure. Unfortunately android has severe limitations because it uses sqlite. You can't even make two tables relational with pk's and fk's. You have to rig them together in a makeshift fashion. I will try and look up some documentation for you. But the short answer is no

Comment: Also, added note, if you want quicker data transfers you will probably have to look into remote databases with some type of webservice.

Comment: Thanks IrishWhiskey. I will look around to see if there is anything else about there about this